# Maven (Java) does not build dependencies into a compiled file

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors

Maven (Java) does not build dependencies into a compiled file.
Here is the code of my main class, the architecture of the application and the contents of the compiled file.

```
import club.minnced.discord.webhook.WebhookClientBuilder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello!");

        WebhookClientBuilder builder = new WebhookClientBuilder("test");
        System.out.println(builder);
    }
}
```

The rest:

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4AdU.png) [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmXZV.png) [image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCWDc.png)

I read the answers to the questions and ended up making a pom.xml file like this:
12345678901234567890123456789123456789023456789345678945678456789

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>me.gusandr</groupId>
    <artifactId>GusStill</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/club.minnced/discord-webhooks -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>club.minnced</groupId>
                        <artifactId>discord-webhooks</artifactId>
                        <version>0.8.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/club.minnced/discord-webhooks -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>club.minnced</groupId>
            <artifactId>discord-webhooks</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIVGs.png)

Comment: The `maven-jar-plugin` doesn't include dependencies in the JAR. You would need to use the `maven-assembly-plugin` or similar.

Comment: I'll check it out